# How to remove the error values by replacing them?

Tags: arrays, list, error-handling, outliers

I have an array with values collected from a sensor. However, once in a while, the sensor returns an error value. I want to replace these values by interpolating them using the closest values in the array. How can I do that easily, considering I can have several error values consecutively?

```
sensor = [20, 21, 22, 21, 8190, 20, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 8190, 8190, 25, 21, 8190]
```

I want to have this:

```
sensor = [20, 21, 22, 21, 20.5, 20, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 24.5, 24.5, 25, 21, 21]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do something like

```
const sensor = [20, 21, 22, 21, 8190, 20, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 8190, 8190, 25, 21, 8190]
```

//create a new array and variable

```
let  arr=[]
let currentNum
```

//iterate over the old array

```
sensor.forEach(element =>{ 
  if(element!==8190){
     arr.push(element)
     currentNum=element
  }else{
    currentNum=currentNum+.5

     arr.push(currentNum)
  }
});



console.log(arr)
```